# Iterate big hashmap in parallel

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream, java-threads

I have a linked hashmap which may contain upto 300k records at maximum. I want to iterate this map in parallel to improve the performance. The function iterates through the map of vectors and finds dot product of given vector against all the vectors in map. Also have one more check based on date value. And the function returns a nested hashmap. T

This is the code using iterator:

```
public HashMap<String,HashMap<String,Double>> function1(String key, int days) {
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.now().minusDays(days);
    HashMap<String,Double> ret = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<String,Double> ret2 = new HashMap<>();
    OpenMapRealVector v0 = map.get(key).value;
    for(Map.Entry<String, FixedTimeHashMap<OpenMapRealVector>> e: map.entrySet()) {
        if(!e.getKey().equals(key)) {
            Double d = v0.dotProduct(e.getValue().value);
            d = Double.parseDouble(new DecimalFormat("###.##").format(d));
            ret.put(e.getKey(),d);
            if(e.getValue().date.isAfter(date)){
                ret2.put(e.getKey(),d);
            }
        }
    }
    HashMap<String,HashMap<String,Double>> result = new HashMap<>();
    result.put("dot",ret);
    result.put("anomaly",ret2);
    return result;
}
```

Update: 
I looked into Java 8 streams, but I am running into CastException and Null pointer exceptions when using the parallel stream as this map is being modified else where.

Code:

```
public HashMap<String,HashMap<String,Double>> function1(String key, int days) {
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.now().minusDays(days);
    HashMap<String,Double> ret = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<String,Double> ret2 = new HashMap<>();
    OpenMapRealVector v0 = map.get(key).value;
    synchronized (map) {
        map.entrySet().parallelStream().forEach(e -> {
            if(!e.getKey().equals(key)) {
                Double d = v0.dotProduct(e.getValue().value);
                d = Double.parseDouble(new DecimalFormat("###.##").format(d));
                ret.put(e.getKey(),d);
                if(e.getValue().date.isAfter(date)) {
                    ret2.put(e.getKey(),d);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have synchronized the map usage, but it still gives me the following errors:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ClassCastException
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap$Node cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap$TreeNode
```

Also, I was thinking Should i split up the map into multiple pieces and run each using different threads in parallel?

Comment: *"I looked into Java 8 streams, but could not get parallel streams implementation for this function."* Show us what you tried, so we can better help you figure out what you did wrong.

Comment: @Andreas , I have updated the question to show the exact issue.

Comment: The error is because parallel = multi-threaded, and you're doing multi-threaded `ret.put(...)` on a `HashMap`, which is not a thread-safe object. Change `ret` and `ret2` to be `ConcurrentHashMap` will fix that problem, then change return value to just be `Map<String, Map<String, Double>>`

Comment: Thank you @Andreras, I was thinking about various things and never checked ret and ret2. This has resolved the issue.

Comment: The accepted solution of Mehdi resolves the issue in the question. The answer of Ravindra is the complete Java 8 solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to retrieve the `Set<Map.Entry<K, V>>` from the map.

Here's how you iterate on a Map using parallel Streams in Java8:

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<> ();
myMap.entrySet ()
    .parallelStream ()
    .forEach (entry -> {
        String key = entry.getKey ();
        String value = entry.getValue ();
        // here add whatever processing you wanna do using the key / value retrieved
        // ret.put (....);
        // ret2.put (....)
    });
```

Clarification:

The maps `ret` and `ret2` should be declared as `ConcurrentHashMap`s to allow the concurrent inserts / updates from multiple threads.

So the declaration of the 2 maps become:

```
Map<String,Double> ret = new ConcurrentHashMap<> ();
Map<String,Double> ret2 = new ConcurrentHashMap<> ();
```

Comment: Of course, doing this requires that `ret` and `ret2` are *concurrent* maps (or synchronized, but concurrent is better).

Comment: Good point @Andreas! I'll update my answer with your clarification.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution using Java 8 would be,

```
Map<String, Double> dotMap = map.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> !e.getKey().equals(key))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> Double
                .parseDouble(new DecimalFormat("###.##").format(v0.dotProduct(e.getValue().value)))));
Map<String, Double> anomalyMap = map.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> !e.getKey().equals(key))
        .filter(e -> e.getValue().date.isAfter(date))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> Double
                .parseDouble(new DecimalFormat("###.##").format(v0.dotProduct(e.getValue().value)))));
result.put("dot", dotMap);
result.put("anomaly", anomalyMap);
```

**Update**

Here's much more elegant solution,

```
Map<String, Map<String, Double>> resultMap = map.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> !e.getKey().equals(key))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getValue().date.isAfter(date) ? "anomaly" : "dot",
                Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> Double.parseDouble(
                        new DecimalFormat("###.##").format(v0.dotProduct(e.getValue().value))))));
```

Here we first group them based on anomaly or dot, and then use a downstream `Collector` to create a `Map` for each group. Also I have updated `.filter()` criteria based on the following suggestions.

Comment: This is probably a cleaner solution, except you should build `anomalyMap` from `dotMap` to avoid double computation.

Comment: @DidierL : But dot map will not have the date value, which is needed for anomaly map.

Comment: Indeed, it should be taken from the original map. It would be good to compare the efficiency of the two solutions.

Comment: @DidierL Yeah its true, i have to also decouple both dotmap and anomalymap if possible for better design. I will look into both and check the performance.

Comment: I assume you meant `filter(e -> ! e.getKey().equals(key))` in both *(added missing **not** operator)*. Otherwise you might as well do a `map.get(key)` and not iterate at all.

Comment: Nice update, I think it is the right way to do it with streams (though you still need to add the anomalies to the `dot` map to be equivalent). Also pay attention that your `filter` is still inverted in both code samples, as noted by @Andreas.